# How to trigger a Numeric Keypad on Mobile devices when we focus on an input field each and every time?

Tags: jquery, html

I've a situation where I need to have my input type defined as a "password" to hide the characters as they are typed. but it needs to behave as number. It is for a SSN input field. How do I do it?

```
<input id="ssn" type="tel" class="ssnentry form-control" value=""/>

$(".ssnentry").on("blur", function () {
            $(this).attr("type", "password");
            }).on("focus", function () {
            $(this).attr("type", "tel");
        });
```

Each and every time the input field is focused, the numeric keypad on the mobile(ios) should be triggered. At the first attempt, Numeric keypad is triggered. But for all the next attempts, Alphabetical Keypad is triggered. How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*">` ?

Comment: Does pattern really affect which keyboard gets shown on mobile?

Comment: Yes, I have tried <input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*>. The alphabetical keypad shows up on focus